# Get table without DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Can I get table without DbSet ?
I need to record table from Stored Procedure to an object or can I record via view ?

I use EF Core 6 and _context.DataBase.SqlQuery("...").ToList - not fount method "SqlQuery"

Comment: Just don't use EF, but Dapper. If you need more help you really have to give more details, i.e. a [mre].

Comment: You can create a VIEW in SQL Server which is a dynamic table in the database.  Than do a SELECT * from Table as the query where the table is the view.

Comment: Use EF Core Power Tools!